# Barcodes Generator for Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, barcode

Is there a way to generate a barcode based on an input value in a Google Sheet, and displays both the value and an additional title?

For example:

```
Value = DPI-001-A02
Title = BB: 1/2/2018
```

The current formula I am using is this:

```
=image("http://www.barcodesinc.com/generator/image.php?code=" & F1 & "&style=164&type=C128B&width=200&height=50&xres=1&font=1", 3)
```

This only displays the barcode and the value `DPI-001-A02`, but I would also like it to display the title: `BB: 1/2/2018`.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by generate a barcode and display both the value an additional image. Consider to add an example of the expected result.

Answer (score 3):

This seems like a limitation of barcodesinc.com. They're the ones outputting the image. If they allow another parameter for "additional title", you could stick the value in there. But Google Sheets don't have features to modify a picture that is output by another site.

Google Sheets don't seem to allow you to concatenate text with an image in the same cell; the following formula just shows the text but omits the barcode:

`="Additional Label" & image("http://www.barcodesinc.com/generator/image.php?code=" & F1 & "&style=164&type=C128B&width=200&height=50&xres=1&font=1", 3)`

The only workaround I can think of is to display the optional title in a separate cell, either above or below the cell with the barcode.